# how can I make my pygame konami code simpler?

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on a pygame game and my friends asked if i could implement a konami code.
I thought it was a great idea so i implemented it.

I made it in a way it would certainly work because I wouldnt have to deal with any errors.
However.. the code got a bit larger then expected so i was wondering how i could make it smaller and still working because i dont know any good way to make it smaller.

the code:

```
konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            if konami_code[0] == '':
                konami_code[0] = 'UP'

            elif konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == '':
                konami_code[1] = 'UP'

            else:
                konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            if konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == '':
                konami_code[2] = 'DOWN'

            elif konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == '':
                konami_code[3] = 'DOWN'

            else:
                konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[4] == '':
                konami_code[4] = 'LEFT'

            elif konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[4] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[5] == 'RIGHT' \
                    and konami_code[6] == '':
                konami_code[6] = 'LEFT'

            else:
                konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
           if konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[4] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[5] == '':
                konami_code[5] = 'RIGHT'

            elif konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[4] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[5] == 'RIGHT' \
                    and konami_code[6] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[7] == '':
                konami_code[7] = 'RIGHT'

            else:
                konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

        if key[pygame.K_b]:
            if konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[4] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[5] == 'RIGHT' \
                    and konami_code[6] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[7] == 'RIGHT' \
                    and konami_code[8] == '':
                konami_code[8] = 'B'

            else:
                konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            if konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
                    and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
                    and konami_code[4] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[5] == 'RIGHT' \
                    and konami_code[6] == 'LEFT' \
                    and konami_code[7] == 'RIGHT' \
                    and konami_code[8] == 'B' \
                    and konami_code[9] == '':
                konami_code[9] = 'A'

            else:
                konami_code = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']



    if konami_code[0] == 'UP' \
        and konami_code[1] == 'UP' \
        and konami_code[2] == 'DOWN' \
        and konami_code[3] == 'DOWN' \
        and konami_code[4] == 'LEFT' \
        and konami_code[5] == 'RIGHT' \
        and konami_code[6] == 'LEFT' \
        and konami_code[7] == 'RIGHT' \
        and konami_code[8] == 'B' \
        and konami_code[9] == 'A':
    print('code completed')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your konami code as a list of values. And then compare user input with that list:

```
import pygame

CODE = [pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_b, pygame.K_a]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
code = []
index = 0
running = True
while running:
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == CODE[index]:
                code.append(event.key)
                index += 1
                if code == CODE:
                    index = 0
                    print('Bingo!')
            else:
                code = []
                index = 0

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually a proper question to ask here (maybe code review is a better place) but I made some improvements to Your code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 20)

sequence = ['up', 'up', 'down', 'right', 'left', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'up', 'down']
text_render = font.render(' '.join(sequence), False, (255, 255, 255))
input_sequence = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                input_sequence.append('up')

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                input_sequence.append('down')

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                input_sequence.append('right')

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                input_sequence.append('left')

            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                input_sequence.append('z')

            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                input_sequence.append('x')

    display.blit(text_render, (10, 10))

    pygame.display.update()
    
    if len(input_sequence) == len(sequence):
        if input_sequence == sequence:
            print('correct sequence')
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        else:
            print('incorrect sequence, try again')
            input_sequence = []
```

The main thing is that now You can input any sequence You want in the sequence list and it will match user input against it, no matter how long the list really. except some adjustment in case of a long list could be made with font size (automate the process) and maybe some timing could be added

here is an even shorter option:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 20)

keys = {pygame.K_UP: 'up', pygame.K_DOWN: 'down', pygame.K_RIGHT: 'right', pygame.K_LEFT: 'left',
        pygame.K_z: 'z', pygame.K_x: 'x'}
sequence = ['up', 'up', 'down', 'right', 'left', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'up', 'down']
text_render = font.render(' '.join(sequence), False, (255, 255, 255))
input_sequence = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            for key, name in keys.items():
                if event.key == key:
                    input_sequence.append(name)
                    break

    display.blit(text_render, (10, 10))

    pygame.display.update()
    
    if len(input_sequence) == len(sequence):
        if input_sequence == sequence:
            print('correct sequence')
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        else:
            print('incorrect sequence, try again')
            input_sequence = []
```